# How to forward events in wxWidgets?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I have a window with a GLCanvas and scroll bars, I want the canvas to capture scroll events and forward them to the scroll bars, which are then used to position the 'camera.' So I've done this:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(wxWindow* parent,wxWindowID id)
{
//...
   GlCanvas->Connect(ID_GLCANVAS1, wxEVT_MOUSEWHEEL, (wxObjectEventFunction)&MainWindow::onMouseWheel, 0L, this);
}

void MainWindow::onMouseWheel(wxMouseEvent & event)
{
    if(event.GetWheelAxis() == wxMOUSE_WHEEL_VERTICAL)
    {
        std::cerr << "vertical scroll" << std::endl;
        verticalScroll->ProcessWindowEvent(event);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cerr << "horizontal scroll" << std::endl;
        horizontalScroll->ProcessWindowEvent(event);
    }
}
```

However, this isn't doing anything aside from the printouts. What do I do to get the scrollbars to process the wheel events?

============== Solution ==============

```
void MainWindow::onMouseWheel(wxMouseEvent & event)
{
    event.Skip();
    double rotation = ((double) event.GetWheelRotation()) / event.GetWheelDelta();

    wxScrollBar * scrollBar;
    double * delta;

    if(event.GetWheelAxis() == wxMOUSE_WHEEL_VERTICAL)
    {
        scrollBar = verticalScroll; 
        delta     = &verticalDelta;
        rotation *= -1;
    }
    else
    {
        scrollBar = horizontalScroll;
        delta     = &horizontalDelta;
    }

    if(event.IsPageScroll())
    {
        rotation *= scrollBar->GetPageSize();
    }
    else
    {
        if(event.GetWheelAxis() == wxMOUSE_WHEEL_VERTICAL)
        {
            rotation *= event.GetLinesPerAction();
        }
        else
        {
            rotation *= event.GetColumnsPerAction();
        }
    }

    *delta += rotation;

    int scroll = scrollBar->GetThumbPosition();
    int ds = (int) *delta;

    *delta -= ds;
    scroll += ds;

    if(scroll < 0)
    {
        *delta = 0;
        scroll = 0;
    }
    else if(scroll > scrollBar->GetRange())
    {
        *delta = 0;
        scroll = scrollBar->GetRange();
    }

    scrollBar->SetThumbPosition(scroll);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't forward wx events to native controls, if you think about it, how would it be possible for this to work when the native controls don't have any idea about wx? Native controls generate native events which are then translated to wx events and given to your application, but nothing happens, or even can be really done, in the other direction.

In this particular case you can (relatively) easily translate scroll events to the calls to `ScrollLines()`, `ScrollPages()` or just `SetScrollPos()`. This will allow you to control another window scrolling using the same scrollbar.

Do *not* forget to call `Skip()` in the original handler to let the window being scrolled from actually scrolling too.

Comment: But aren't all wx classes things that translate the wxEvents and forward them to native controls?

Comment: It's the other way. Native controls send events and wx allows (by e.g. `conect()`) that you handle them in your function.

Comment: @Ripi2 is correct, but I've updated the answer to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `conect()`, or better `bind()` if your wx version allows it, a [wxScrollEvent](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_scroll_event.html)

If you choose to handle all scroll events by using **wxEVT_COMMAND_SCROLL** or **wxEVT_SCROLL** then you can get the type of event from the event parameter in your handler function.

### Correction:

Currently (wx 3.1) still there's no wxEVT_COMMAND_SCROLL nor wxEVT_SCROLL. Only partial definitions (page up, thumtrack, etc). It seems a bug. But you can use EVT_SCROLL in the old BEGIN_EVENT_TABLE/END_EVENT_TABLE way.

Comment: wxEVT_COMMAND_SCROLL and wxEVT_SCROLL both get a `not declared` error.

Comment: it's wx 3.0 btw, and the comments in the wxEVT declarations clearly state that wxEVT_SCROLL should be used rather than wxEVT_SCROLLBAR.

Comment: @PatrickJeeves, you need to Skip() the event, i.e. add "event.Skip() at the end of the handler.

Comment: @igor it didn't change anything. Could it have to do with being on KDE?

Comment: @PatrickJeeves, you did compile against GTK+ though, right? Was it GTK+2 or 3?

Comment: @Igor I just used `wx-config --cxxflags`, which seems to be outputting gtk2-unicode-3.0 for that.

Comment: @PatrickJeeves, ok, I see Vadim' responce. Please follow his suggestion and like he said - don't forget to call "event.Skip()".

Comment: @Igor not sure who vadim is, but I just tried the EVT_SCROLL in the event table, the in addition to not working, the printouts aren't being printed, so the glcanvas isn't generating scroll events i guess? I tried enabling the style  wxHSCROLL and wxVSCROLL, not sure what they do but they don't work. If you meant the other guy, I'm not seeing exactly how I would translate a mouse wheel to SetScrollPos, i thought that was the point of the scrollbar class, in addition the docs indicate it isn't always implemented.